# Error Only inside Unity not Visual studio, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This line of code gives me the error

> error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

```
public Transform target { get; protected set; } = null;
```

I don't get if I'm doing the get and set in a wrong way. I was following a tutorial and I works just fine for the dude. Also the error only appears inside Unity. Visual studio don't give me any error message.

Comment: That is short hand and fairly new syntax. Maybe your version of unity or vs doesn't support it.

Comment: What if you use a backing field instead of the short hand. Does it work?

Comment: @Heriberto Lugo  I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity versions older than 2017 do not support C# 6.0 features such as [property initializers](https://csharp.today/c-6-features-auto-property-initializers/).

Use a simple backing field initialization, or upgrade to the latest Unity (2019) which supports [C# 7.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html)

Edit:

since objects always default to null

```
public Transform target { get; protected set; } = null;
```

is same as

```
public Transform target { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: Tks, I did just that.